# Leap Motion Controller connection with windows 7

Tags: leap-motion

I am trying to connect my leap motion controller to my windows pc. Leap motion controller is showing green light but device is not operatable. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You need to install the airspace app store on your machine, download apps through the store and use the device with those apps. The airspace launches only today.

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 2):

Are you getting any errors? Have you installed any software from leap-motion?

You don't give enough details for us to help you...

Are you part of the beta program or today's release? If it's the second option, I think you have to activate your device somewhere (haven't received mine yet)...

Comment: Go to https://www.leapmotion.com/setup and when it's launched you will be able to activate it and download the software needed. Support will be here if you have any trouble with it...

Answer (score 0):

You have to download and launch setup from the leap website to get it to do anything. Also when you run setup, if nothing happens, try running it in administrator mode (right click setup, then click "run as administrator").

Answer (score 0):

Few other tips:

1. Disable Windows User Account Control in user settings, causes havoc with the software.
2. Disable any Anti-Virus you have or add the Leap Software to the exclusions if you can (AirSpace phones home a lot).
3. Once you've got it running be sure to check for any software updates.
4. You can get a lot of tips and trouble-shooting advice here: https://forums.leapmotion.com/forum.php

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed all the necessary software from the leap motion website, there should be no problem. Make sure the drivers are installed. The green light I believe means that it is connected to the computer. The leap motion symbol should appear at the bottom right of the taskbar, and either green or yellow if it is working. Try launching the orientation software, or installing touchless for windows and following the instructions on their website. After you install touchless for windows, in the bottom right of the taskbar, make sure it is set to basic or advanced. Otherwise it won't work. Right-Click on the 3 circles, and select either basic or advanced.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem, and when I have restarted my machine (win 7), the device works!

Hope this help.